# Creating and saving non-empty Django model instance as part of subclass instance

Tags: django, django-models, instance

I am experiencing a very strange behavior inconsistent with the Django documentation while creating and saving (inserting into DB) model instance. I've already run out of ideas for possible reason and will be very grateful for any suggestions  **why Django fails to save all fields in these cases**.

This  class I am using:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    address     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

And here's code that does't work, few cases:

```
# First Case
new_person = Person()
new_person.user = request.user
new_person.phone_number = '111111'
new_person.save(force_insert=True)

# Second One
new_person = Person(user=request.user, phone_number='111111')
new_person.save(force_insert=True)

# Third One 
new_person = Person.objects.create(user=request.user, phone_number='111111')
```

Basing on [official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) in any case django should create an object and insert it into DB.

In fact the object is successfully created (and all relevant fields are set), but row inserted into DB has only `id` and `user_id` fields filled correctly while `phone_number` field that was also set, remains blank.

There is, however, no problem to access and update all fields of existing (saved earlier) objects.

Removing `blank=True` from `Person` class declaration (with proper table alteration) does't change anything.

**EDIT:**
Problem turned out to be more sophisticated. Full description and solution in my own answer beneath

Comment: The third one should be `Person.objects.create`  and not `Person.objects.Create` - lower case `c`

Comment: When you remove `blank=True`, it is a change to the database table structure. Django does not recognize this by default. You would have to drop database and recreate using syncdb (painful .. ), or run an alter table script to not allow null values.

Comment: @karthikr  #1 Thank you for your correction, but this just little mistake made only in this Q. #2 I should have mentioned it, but I have also changed null settings in the table

Comment: @karthikr: blank=True only refers to form fields, it has no bearing on the db fields. null=True is for db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an explanation....

It has something to do with inheritance, namely further in the code I wanted to create instance of Person's subclass. So there was another class:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    address     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class ConnectedPerson(Person):
    connection = models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass)
    # etc..
```

And after creating instance of Person, intending to extend it to ConnectedPerson I made such code:

```
#creating instance of Person:
person = Person(user=request.user, phone_number='111111')
person.save(force_insert=True)

c_person = ConnectedPerson(id=person.id, connection=instance_of_another_c)
```

and using `ConnectedPerson(id=person.id)` was in fact **killing previously created Person instance** by overwritting it in the DB.

---

So for anyone not too much experienced in managing inheriting instances: **if you need to use earlier created super class instance as part of subclass instance** do it this way:

```
#creating person but not saving it
person = Person(user=request.user, phone_number='111111')

######
#later
###### 

#creating subclass instance and saving
c_person = ConnectedPerson(user=request.user, connection=instance_of_another_c)
c_person.save()

#saving super class instance as part of subclass instance
person.pk = super(ConnectedPerson, c_person).pk
person.save()
```